# Simple question about topologies

Tags: general-topology, rational-numbers

> Let $A=\{(x,y,x+y)|x\in \mathbb{Q},y\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ with the Subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

My only question is-does it mean that $A=\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$? (Knowing that the sum of two rationals is rational).

Comment: No. It means that $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb Q^3$. It contains e.g. $(1,1,2)$ but not $(1,1,1)$ simply because $1+1=2$.

Comment: Points in the plane $x + y -z = 0$ with with all coordinates rational.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $A$ is just a proper subspace of $\mathbb{Q}^3$.
Note that $(x,x,x)\not\in A$ for any $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x\not=0$.

Answer (score 3):

No. We have $A \subseteq\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ but $A \ne \mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$.

For example we have $(0,0,1) \in \mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$, but  $(0,0,1) \notin A$.