# Simple question about topologies and products

Tags: general-topology

> Let $A=\{(x,y,x+y)|x\in \mathbb{Q},y\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ with the Subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

My only question is-does it mean that $A=\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\times B$? Where $B$ is some other topology .

Comment: Are you asking what it means for $A$ to have the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^3$, or what it means for $A$ to be the set $\{(x, y, x+y) : x, y\in \mathbb{Q}\}$?

Comment: Or are you asking whether we can write $A$ as a Cartesian product? The answer to that last question is "no."

Comment: Almost the same question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2393039/simple-question-about-topologies

Comment: @MichaelLee I am asking if we can write $A$ as a product of $\mathbb{Q}^2$ and some other $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the elements were real, then as a set $A$ would be a plane in $\mathbb R^3$. So there is a homeomorphism of $A$ to $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$. Hence $A$ has the subspace topology of $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R^3$ which is the same as the subspace topology of $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R^2$ which has a product subspace topology. So the answer to your question is no, there is no $B$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is a $B$, namely the one point space.